# Count posts of user with default value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Supposed I have a data of

```
[
    {
        "_id": "629eb5ced774223d36a68907",
        "userId": "629eb22698df1015e980a98f",
        "posts": [
            {
                "_id": "629eb59ad774223d36a688fa",
                "title": "titletestz",
                "body": "bodyz",
                "createdAt": "2022-06-07T02:19:06.314Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-06-07T02:19:06.314Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "629eb59ad774223d36a688fc",
                "title": "titletestx",
                "body": "bodyx",
                "createdAt": "2022-06-07T02:19:06.879Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-06-07T02:19:06.879Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2022-06-07T02:19:58.206Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-06-07T02:19:58.206Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "629ebf8b775b5cd326b1c41c",
        "userId": "629eb22698df1015e980a98f",
        "posts": [
            {
                "_id": "629eb22c98df1015e980a995",
                "title": "ttle3",
                "body": "ttile3",
                "createdAt": "2022-06-07T02:04:28.787Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-06-07T02:04:28.787Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2022-06-07T03:01:31.065Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-06-07T03:01:31.065Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

I want to count the posts of a specific user

```
let start = new Date()
start = start.setHours(0,0,0,0)

let end = new Date()
end = start.setHours(23,59,59,999)

model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId,
      createdAt: {
        $gte: start,
        $lt: end
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind : '$posts',
  },
  {
    $count: 'count'
  }
])
```

now it does work

```
[
  {
    "total": 3
  }
]
```

however, I want to set a default value of `0` of user if it doesn't contain any posts, like this:

```
[
  {
    "total": 0
  }
]
```

right now I just having a response of an empty array `[]` if user doesn't have any posts.

any idea how can I achieve this using aggregate in monggo?

Comment: Match by filter -> unwind posts -> group by user and count posts -  this may work. The `$unwind` has an option to preserve empty / null arrays - you can possibly use this.

Comment: Hi I update the sample data, the data can have a same userId like show aboved.

Comment: updated query,  even if I used group with userId and total: $sum 1 the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better avoid `unwind` if possible. The simple way is just `$group` and `$sum` up the number of posts on each document. This will return 0 if there is no posts for this user. You can run it on multiple users together, if you want

**EDIT**: use `$facet` to solve users that has no documents:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $facet: {
    count: [{
      $match: {
        userId,
        createdAt: {$gte: start, $lt: end}
      }
    },
    {$group: {_id: "$userId", total: {$sum: {$size: "$posts"}}}}
  ]},
  {
    $project: {
      total: {$ifNull: [{$arrayElemAt: ["$count.total", 0]}, 0]}}
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IKVC8KfwzkR)

Comment: however if there is no user match with userId it will return an empty array. It should return the total object with 0 value

Comment: if no result on $match filter it should be able to return total as 0 and  if user has no posts available like empty task `task: []` it also should return total as 0

Comment: there's an answer below. totally like that and it is correct u can check it by 1sina1, but im exploring other queries if theres other better answer

Comment: `$group` is better than `$unwind`

Answer (score 2):

using `$facet` and `$ifNull`

[mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_YSRbw24eDe)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      count: [
        {
          $match: {
            userId,
            createdAt: {
              $gte: start,
              $lt: end
            }
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$posts" },
        { "$count": "total" }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "total": {
        "$ifNull": [
          { "$arrayElemAt": ["$count.total", 0] },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

It Will return empty array on no matches.

```
let start = new Date()
start = start.setHours(0,0,0,0)

let end = new Date()
end = start.setHours(23,59,59,999);

db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: {
      userId,
      createdAt: {
        $gte: start,
        $lt: end
      }
    }
    },
    {
      $group: {
         '$posts'
      }
    },
    {
      $count: "totalCount"
    }
  ]
)
```